# Codeigniter - Use the id from a query result in a model to query in a different function in the same model

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, model

I'm using codeigniter to code my site and I'm running into a roadblock. I know how to do this in regular, non "MVC", not OOP PHP, but am struggling on it in Codeigniter.

I have blog_model.php, which has a function to retrieve the datetime from my database, explode it into an array so that I can work with it outside the model and feed it into CSS where I have individual calendar icons for it. Each calendar icon is loaded by the month number in the view (`<div class='calendar-icon-$stats['date']`). This function also pulls the amount of comments from that individual post and outputs it into an array so that I can show it in the view.

```
public function get_stats($id) {
  $this->db->select('id,datetime')->from('blog_posts')->where('id',$id);
  $dquery = $this->db->get();
  $dquery = $dquery->row_array();
  $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dquery['datetime']));
  $stats = explode("-", $date); // This makes $stats[0] the year, $stats[1] the month and $stats[2] the day.
  $stats['time'] = date('H:i', strtotime($dquery['datetime']));
  $stats['comcount'] = $this->db->get_where('blog_comments', array('blogid' => $id));
  $stats['comcount'] = $stats['comcount']->num_rows();
  return $stats;
}
```

There is also a function to retrieve the three most recent entries:

```
public function get_blog_last() {
  $query = $this->db->order_by('id desc')->get('blog_posts',3);
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

This code is then loaded into my controller and sent to the view to be displayed:

```
$data['blog'] = $this->blog_model->get_blog_last();
$data['stats'] = $this->blog_model->get_stats($data['blog']);
$this->load->view('index',$data);
```

The problem I face is how to get the get_stats() function to run for every entry I have on the index page, where the last three entries are displayed. So far I can only get it to run for one of them, therefore all three of the entries on my front page have the same date, the same time and the same amount of comments. I figured putting the code in a model would save myself from repeating myself when I had to load it for the archives page (where I display all the posts from the month) and the main entry page where I just display that entry and its comments.

So, the ultimate question here is:

- How do I run get_stats for every entry I have on a given page?

I'm also having a bit of issue figuring out the correct value to pass to my get_stats() function.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to call `get_stats` for each of the three entries that you receive in `get_blog_last`. If that is the case, just change `get_blog_last` to this:

```
public function get_blog_last() {
  $query = $this->db->order_by('id desc')->get('blog_posts',3);
  $entries = $query->result_array();         // get the latest entries array
  foreach ($entries as $index => $entry) {   // loop through those entries
    $stats = $this->get_stats($entry['id']); // call this model's `get_stats` method
    $entries[$index]['stats'] = $stats;      // add a `stats` key to the entry array
  }
  return $entries;
}
```

Comment: Blah. That's so simple! I feel dumb. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put

```
$this->blog_model->get_stats($data['blog']);
```

inside loop ? ( i'd rather use normal loop )

example :

```
$stat_list = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($data['blog']);$i++){
    $stat_list[] = $this->blog_model->get_stats($data['blog'][$i]);
}
$data['stats'] = $stat_list;
```

and in your view, you should try the same to print out each `$stat_list`